# Port not open (ufw disabled)

Tags: networking, server, firewall, connection, ufw

On the server, running Ubuntu 22.04

```
sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :4000

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10690/nxd           
tcp6       0      0 :::4000                 :::*                    LISTEN      10690/nxd
```

The service responds to HTTP request:

```
curl localhost:4000
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

ufw is disabled

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

From client (same subnet) machine:

```
nc -zv 192.168.1.111 4000
nc: connect to 192.168.1.111 port 4000 (tcp) failed: No route to host
```

SSh is enabled

```
nc -zv 192.168.1.111 22
Connection to 192.168.1.111 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

Ping works:

```
ping 192.168.1.111
PING 192.168.1.111 (192.168.1.111) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.111: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=309 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to be able to post a comment - so an answer will have to do...

You've checked 'ufw' but you could have a different firewall configured. Try the following :

```
sudo firewall-cmd --state
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```

If the state is enabled ("running") you can add port 4000 with :

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port 4000/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port 4000/tcp
```